# Как научиться создавать слайдеры для от простых до самых сложных

Tags: jquery, css3, javascript, css

Всем привет. Хочу научиться делать слайдеры, начиная от самых простых до более сложных.
Может кто-нибудь дать ссылку на курс или уроки, где всё поэтапно объясняется?

Comment: Для того чтобы делать слайдеры, должны быть знания html, css and js.
____
Хотя мое мнение зачем изобретать велосипед, если этих слайдеров предостаточно - вот, как варинат: http://nordev.ru/articles/article/55

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я недавно тоже училась делать слайдеры, и мне помог разбор кода вот этого [простого слайдера](http://codepen.io/doodlemarks/pen/aFcly). На нем можно экспериментировать сколько угодно: сделать автопрокрутку, сделать слайдер адаптивным, сделать из него карусель и т.д. В codepen.io можно найти еще много слайдеров, разобрать и модифицировать их код. Мне это очень помогло.

Answer (score 4):

А вот, например, для начала: http://htmlforum.ru/index.php?showtopic=23096

Comment: Хотя куда важнее научиться НЕ делать слайдеры. :)

Comment: Я так понял, что сейчас лучше научиться верстать на 5 и как следует освоить js.

Comment: Это, конечно, да.
Но я имела в виду немного другое.
Почитайте как-нибудь на досуге:
http://zadolba.li/story/15571
http://zadolba.li/story/15603

Comment: @Nasty Pacman, это когда люди, которые понятия не имеют о принципах хорошего дизайна, начинают этот самый дизайн ваять. ) Сколько сайтов такие народные умельцы запросто похоронили.